# Updating CListView when deleting records in yii

Tags: yii

I am using yii and i want to update my clistview after a product is deleted from it.
Here is the **clistview widget code**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'viewData'=>array('exhibitorId'=>$exhibitorId),
        'id'=>'productView',
    'itemView'=>'_productView',
        'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        'productName',
        'productType',
        'productBrand',
        'description'
    )
)); ?>
```

Here is the **_productView**

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode(Products::model()->getAttributeLabel('creationDate')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data['creationDate']); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode(Products::model()->getAttributeLabel('updatedBy')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data['updatedBy']); ?>
    <br />
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Delete', array('deleteMyThisProduct', 'product'=>$data['productId'],'exhibitor'=>$exhibitorId),
                array(
                    "beforeSend" => 'js:function(){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))return true;}',
                    "success"=>'js:function(data){'
                    . '$.fn.yiiListView.update("productView");'
                    . '}',
                    "type"=>'post',

                    )); ?>
```

and here is the action that the ajax link goes to

```
public function actionDeleteMyThisProduct($product,$exhibitor)
        {
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            {
            $productId=(int)$product;
            $exhibitorId=(int)$exhibitor;
            if($productId !== 0 && $exhibitorId !== 0)
            {
            $deleteProduct=  Exhibitorproducts::model()->loadRecordsByexhibitorIdAndProductId($exhibitorId, $productId);
            ProductPhotos::model()->deleteAllPhotosByExhibitorIdAndProductId($exhibitorId, $productId);
            if(!empty($deleteProduct))
            {   
                $deleteProduct->delete();
            }
            }
            }

        }
```

**Question:-**
Now the problem is that for the very first time when i delete the product from the clistview. It deletes the product very well and updates the list too. But after that when i click delete link for next product it does nothing. so how can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your event is attached to the `<a>` tag when the whole page loads and no events attached after ajax refresh.

In your product view wrap the whole content with a `<span>` tag:

```
<span class="product" data-product-id="<?php echo $data['productId']; ?>"> .... </span>
```

Change your script to something like this:

```
$('#productView').on('click','.product', function(e){
   var $target = $(e.target);
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post('<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('deleteMyThisProduct') ?>', {'product': $target.data('product-id')}).
   done(function(){
       $.fn.yiiListView.update("productView");
   })

})
```

Comment: Although i solved the problem yesterday only and with the same solution you gave. Anyways thanks for answering and helping me out... cheers :)